# Citrix Simulation API SDK with Citrix Receiver

Tags: sdk, autoit, citrix, receiver

I am trying to use the "Simulation API SDK" for a Citrix Session, to get information about the running processes in an AutoIt script.

The SDK documentation is available here:
https://www.citrix.de/community/receiver-ica-sdks.html
To use the API, the file WfIcaLib.dll is needed, which is placed at Programs/Citrix/ICA Client/WfIcaLib.dll

The modern "Citrix Receiver" has no such file and I couldn't find any way to install this SDK. The SDK itself still seems to be modern, even if the documentation is some years old.
Is there any way to use this SDK with the modern Citrix Receiver (version 4.4) or am I just wasting my time?

If this is not possible, is there any good alternative for this API, to get information about Citrix processes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, this SDK worked for you? 
Were you able to at least start a remote session and launch one app in the client side?

thanks!

Comment: Yes, this SDK works for me. Using it, I am able to either launch a full desktop connection or to lauch a single app. Getting information like existing window titles in citrix desktop also works. Until now it was only successful on a windows 7 machine for me. Win10 may also work, but I stopped trying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occured on a windows 10 machine with the newest Citrix receiver.
I installed the same Citrix receiver on a windows 7 machine and the dll file is available now.
Seems like it gets installed different/without the dll file on windows 10.